# unity gitignore on mac, will not exclude library files

Tags: git, macos, unity-game-engine, github, gitignore

The problem: I have a project that I have to use a mac for - I want to push the repo to a remote on my github but my gitignore is causing an absolute headache.

It isnt ignoring the unity library at all.

```
# This .gitignore file should be placed at the root of your Unity project directory
#
# Get latest from https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore
#
/[Ll]ibrary/
/[Tt]emp/
/[Oo]bj/
/[Bb]uild/
/[Bb]uilds/
/[Ll]ogs/
/[Mm]emoryCaptures/

# Never ignore Asset meta data
!/[Aa]ssets/**/*.meta

# Uncomment this line if you wish to ignore the asset store tools plugin
# /[Aa]ssets/AssetStoreTools*

# TextMesh Pro files
[Aa]ssets/TextMesh*Pro/

# Autogenerated Jetbrains Rider plugin
[Aa]ssets/Plugins/Editor/JetBrains*

# Visual Studio cache directory
.vs/

# Gradle cache directory
.gradle/

# Autogenerated VS/MD/Consulo solution and project files
ExportedObj/
.consulo/
*.csproj
*.unityproj
*.sln
*.suo
*.tmp
*.user
*.userprefs
*.pidb
*.booproj
*.svd
*.pdb
*.mdb
*.opendb
*.VC.db

# Unity3D generated meta files
*.pidb.meta
*.pdb.meta
*.mdb.meta

# Unity3D generated file on crash reports
sysinfo.txt

# Builds
*.apk
*.unitypackage

# Crashlytics generated file
crashlytics-build.properties
```

Im in the early stages of the project so i've been able to completely delete the directory and start over using 'rm -fr .git' , i have tried untracking all files using 'git rm --cached -r .' these work, but when I 'git add .' it doesnt ignore the library, and when i check 'git status' the library is staged.

The .gitignore is saved in the root of the directory and I have tried checking 'git check-ignored' to see if its actually functioning but it doesn't come up with anything - which made me think that the git ignore wasn't working - I then checked to see if this was because the .gitignore was saved as a .rtf - it was and I removed the .rtf extension and it still doesn't work - so I'm at a loss.

I hope this is formatted okay.

Thanks in advance,

A

Comment: `git add .` is pretty sloppy.  Have you really added so many files that manually verifying each one by name is so insurmountably tedious?  That notwithstanding, unless you show us what files you expect to match your .gitignore, and don't ,  we dan't do much to help you

Comment: Could you show us your actual folder content? in general sounds more like a general `git` issues and not really related to Unity directly

Comment: Can you check the output of `file .gitignore` ? it should print details such as file encoding, presence of a BOM ...

Comment: So I've solved this I made this .gitignore in the textedit app on the mac and saved it as .gitignore. (you have to add the second dot for system files on macs) then it still saves it as a .rtf file so I was going into the 'get info' menu on the .gitignore and deleting the extension. you simply have to type 'touch .gitignore' in terminal which creates the file for you - more fool me for trying to use a mac like a pc.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple answer, I just used the mac specific command:

`touch .gitignore`

Which generates a .gitignore for you, from here you can open and edit the file it has made and paste in your gitignore gubbins.